# How can I specify the event type with OnCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've been trying to get my head around the `OnCommand` attribute, as I understand it can help you write more concise and clean code.
I saw a post explaining the difference between `OnCommand` and `OnClick`, but is there a way to set the event that causes the command to fire?

example - I have a button here that I want to press in order to sort some data displayed  with a repeater with the `BindReapeater()` function, is there a way I can execute the command when the mouse hovers over it for example, instead of when clicking?

c#:

```
protected void sortbtn_click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "alphabetical")
    {
        Session["sort_by"] = "Title";

    }
    else if (e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "new")
    {
        Session["sort_by"] = "PublishDate";
    }
    else if (e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "top")
    {
        Session["sort_by"] = "Rating";
    }

    BindRepeater();
}
```

Page:

```
<p class="sortby_text"> Sort By:</p>
<asp:Button ID="sort_by_new_button" Text="New" runat="server" 
    CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="new" />
<asp:Button ID="sort_by_top_button" Text="Top" runat="server" 
    CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="top" />
<asp:Button ID="sort_alphabetically_button" Text="Alphabetical" 
   runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="alphabetical" />
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're using ASP.NET WebForms in 2018? It's been deprecated since 2008 and isn't supported by ASP.NET Core anymore.

Comment: @Dai it's for a school project and that's what we're currently using, but what do you mean it's deprecated? what's the alternative?

Comment: By "deprecated" I mean it's effectively an obsolete and dead-end platform. Microsoft hasn't released any new feature updates to WebForms in years (mostly security related). WebForms' "ideology" of *simulating* a stateful application (through tricks like Viewstate, Controls, etc) was an interesting experiment but its inherent shortcomings cause experienced web-developers to grow to despise the platform. That's why ASP.NET MVC (which replaced WebForms in 2008 with a radically different architecture) is so much more popular and became the basis for ASP.NET Core when that launched in 2015.